# MySQL pagination order issue

Tags: mysql, pagination

The issue:
When I sort data I may see a certain row at the bottom of my results,.  Then I go to page 2 of results, and I see that same row at the top of those results.  I see that the column I am sorting by, has multiple rows with the same column value.  So it would seem that the order of the columns after the first order by is done is random/arbitrary.

I'd like the order to be the same all the time, with no repeats on separate pages.

Does anyone know of a way to get this to happen?

I've thought about perhaps caching the unpaginated results of a query and perhaps sorting it myself.  Or perhaps MySQL results caching will save all results, and then pull paginated results from its cache?  Or does it just save based on the total query, pagination and all, so it would only ever save the amount I'm pulling?

Thank you for your time.

More info:
The tables where I'm pulling data re not being altered between any of these tests.

An example of the problem would be:

On one page I search for subjects with attribute q and sort by age.
3 subjects returned:

```
id   attribute   age
10       q        20
8        q        23
3        q        23
```

I do the same search on a different page:

```
id   attribute   age
10       q        20
3        q        23
8        q        23
```

The order may change  when the ages are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the id column as your secondary search column (if it is unique). Your order will always be consistent and won't give you a random sorted list.

Comment: ty, did not know I could chain orderby's.